# Is it possible to ask for password when enable false or removing chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm kinda new in developing chrome extension. My extension is actually about blocking some web pages, where user can insert domain names of websites that he/she want to block so that children cannot see the page, such as adult content pages, etc.

But I'm facing a problem with the question "How if the children unable or remove the extension, or even unchecked the 'allow in incognito'?" Then it would all be useless. So I am searching for a way to solve this problem, probably with using password before unable/remove the extension/unchecked the 'allow in incognito'.

Here is my manifest file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "AmanNet",
  "description": "Extension ini memblok halaman yang dianggap berbahaya secara konten html.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_16x16.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "AmanNet"
  },
  "options_page": "pengaturan.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "icons": { 
    "128": "icon_128x128.png" 
  },
  "permissions": [
        "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "exclude_matches": ["http://*.google.com/*","https://*.google.com/*"],
        "js": [
            "content.js"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames": false
    }
  ]
}
```

How am I going to do this? Should I add something to manifest, or else? Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not solvable with a Chrome Extension in the general case.

**Google has made every step possible in the direction of making the user empowered to remove unwanted extensions. This is because extensions are a notorious malware vector.**

For instance, there is a method for external software to install their extensions through the registry. Since it was introduced, the following measures were taken:

- Only extensions hosted on the Web Store are allowed (to enable takedowns by Google)
- The user will be expressly asked whether they want that extension activated.
- If they decline or uninstall the extension, it will be *blacklisted* on that profile and cannot be installed via registry again.

There are exceptions to the rule: enterprise installs. An extension on [ExtensionInstallForcelist](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist) domain policy cannot be uninstalled or deactivated. This is, however, not an option for most users.

You can do some clever hacks with 2 separate extensions and [`management` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management), but you can't prevent uninstall, only detect it.

*Note that Chrome includes a feature called "supervised users". However, it has its problems - it deals with the question of unwanted extensions/apps by just [blanket banning](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=354178)* all *of them. If I was to set up parental control, I wouldn't accept a solution that would not allow AdBlock.*

**Bottom line:** there is no chance preventing extension uninstall by extensions themselves, and no "good" ways of doing so with external programs. Custom parental control can only be effective if implemented outside Chrome (and even then questionably effective).

Answer (score 1):

Typically you won't be able to prevent removal of any extensions. Chrome does have a "Kiosk" mode which is designed to be tamper proof but is only for Chrome OS: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled

Answer (score 0):

There is no protection against removal. But you could use some steganography/obfuscation technics, like embedding your extension in another one.